# error in the REPL with a simple MultiMap example

Tags: scala, collections, read-eval-print-loop

I'm testing a simple `MultiMap` example in the REPL.
Why do I encounter this error ?

```
scala> val mm = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]
mm: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] with scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[Int,String] = Map()

scala> mm.addBinding(1, "a")
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $anon$1.addBinding(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/MultiMap;
```

Comment: Do any other MultiMap/HashMap methods work? Looks like that there is a classpath issue.

Comment: methods on `Map` works, other methods on `MultiMap` doesn't work

Comment: This works for me. What version of Scala are you running?

Comment: Scala 2.10.3 / SBT 0.13.1